# next-i18next Problem with multiple links redirecting to the same location

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next, next-i18next

```js
<Typography.Text type="secondary">
    <Trans i18nKey="settings:Configurations.GDPRConsentEmail.Subtext">
        Participants will receive a consent email that explains
        the{' '}
        <Link
            className="text-geekblue-600 "
            href="https://privacy-policy"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
        >
            Privacy Policy
        </Link>
        and{' '}
        <Link
            className="text-geekblue-600"
            href="https://data-processing-addendump"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
        >
            {' '}
            Data Processing Addendum{' '}
        </Link>
        before the meeting. This option is suggested if your
        business operates in regions where data protection
        regulation GDPR is in effect.
    </Trans>
</Typography.Text>
```

This is my imports:

```js
import { Trans, useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import Link from 'next/link';
```

We have a panel and we are updating the links with the <2></2> tag. Currently, it takes direction in both languages ​​from the privacy policy link above. Although the href=""s are different, it directs to the same place. I tried it with the  tag and it still didn't work.